# Unable to receive SNMPv3 Traps few times after the first Send. [snmp4j-Java]

Tags: java, snmp, sender, receiver, snmp4j

I'm struggling from past few days to send SNMPV3 trap using Auth and priv phrase. The problem is : After i receive the first Trap SNMPv3 with Auth-Priv, i cannot receive the trap after sometimes (about 2minutes) . The receiver is like ignoring every trap which is coming.

Here is my Code  :

**The Receiver.java**

```
    try {
        // set udpAdress and transportMapping
        final UdpAddress udpAddress = new UdpAddress(162);
        final TransportMapping transportMapping = new          DefaultUdpTransportMapping(udpAddress);

        // Protocole de sécurité +usm +snmp
        this.snmp = new Snmp(new MessageDispatcherImpl(), transportMapping);
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols();
        final USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(),
            new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID(new OctetString())),
            0);
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new PrivDES());
        usm.setEngineDiscoveryEnabled(true);

        // Add the MPv
        snmp.getMessageDispatcher().addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv1());
        snmp.getMessageDispatcher().addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c());
        snmp.getMessageDispatcher().addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv3(usm));

        // Security model
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

        // Add user 
        snmp.getUSM().addUser(new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESSecName"),
            new UsmUser(new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESSecName"), AuthMD5.ID,
                new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESAuthPassword"), PrivDES.ID,
                new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESPrivPassword")));

        // Launch of the listener
        this.snmp.addCommandResponder(this);
        snmp.listen();`
```

**The Sender.java**

```
try {
        // set udpAdress and transportMapping
        Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse("udp:" + ipAddress + "/" + port);
        TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

        // Protocole de sécurité +usm +snmp
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols();
        final USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(),
            new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID(new OctetString())),
            0);

        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new PrivDES());
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

        transport.listen();

        // Ajout d'un user avec les paramètres de sécurité
        snmp.getUSM().addUser(new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESSecName"),
            new UsmUser(new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESSecName"), AuthMD5.ID,
                new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESAuthPassword"), PrivDES.ID,
                new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESPrivPassword")));

        // Create Target
        UserTarget target = new UserTarget();
        target.setAddress(targetAddress);
        target.setRetries(1111);
        target.setTimeout(11111500);
        target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
        target.setSecurityLevel(SecurityLevel.AUTH_PRIV);
        target.setSecurityName(new OctetString("v3AuthSHAPrivDESSecName"));

        // Create PDU 1 for V3
        ScopedPDU pdu = new ScopedPDU();
        pdu.setType(PDU.TRAP);
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.sysUpTime));
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID, SnmpConstants.linkDown));
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString("V33333")));
        snmp.send(pdu, target);

        System.out.println("Sending Trap to (IP:Port)=> " + ipAddress + ":" + port);

        snmp.addCommandResponder(new CommandResponder() {
            public void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(arg0);
            }
        });
        snmp.close();
```

- I'm using the snmp4j-1.1 dependency. I don't know why it ignore the traps which come about 2minute after the first the send.

  Many Thanks friends for your helps

Comment: Hello friends, i add some edit in my question , speciellay "Hii friends :) " but it doesnt take my edit x) ,
Thanks in advance for your help and idea, big up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! :D Just change the dependency to snmp4j-2.* and it works, now i used the snmp4j-2.5.0. and it work perfect, the code above work perfect if you want to use it.

Have a nice code day :-)